# Homophones/Homonyms/Homographs

Tags: homophones, homonyms, homographs, heteronyms

I've been searching on Google for a while now regarding homophones, homonyms and homographs, and I constructed a table to easily categorise words.

|  | Homophone | Homonym | Homograph | Heteronym |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pronunciation | Same |  |  |  |
| Spelling | Different |  | Same |  |
| Meaning | Different |  | Different |  |

The problem is, I'm still confused as to their meanings. I'm interested in some professional definitions of the three word types (and if possible, of a heteronym) and also some help with completing my table.

Here's a diagram I found, but I found it a bit too messy to be able to be read:

[image: Homophone: same pronunciation, different meaning; Homograph: same spelling, different meaning; Heterograph: different meaning and spelling, e.g. too/two; Homonym: Different meaning, e.g. tire (car wheel)/tire (fatigue); Synonym: different spelling and pronunciation]

Comment: "homonym" can mean either "homophone" or "homophone and homograph".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikipedia entry for [homonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) has a table like yours:

| Term | Meaning | Spelling | Pronunciation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Homonym | Different | Same | Same |
| Homograph | Different | Same | (No requirement) |
| Homophone word | Different | (No requirement) | Same |
| Homophone phrase | Different | Different | Same to varying degree |
| Heteronym | Different | Same | Different |
| Heterograph | Different | Different | Same |
| Polyseme | Different but related | Same | (No requirement) |
| Capitonym | Different when capitalized | Same except for capitalization | (No requirement) |
| Synonym | Same | Different | Different |
| Antonym | Opposite | Different | Different |
| Auto-antonym | Opposite | Same | (No requirement) |
| Synophone | Different | Different | Similar |

Answer (score 2):

Homophones are words which are pronounced in same way but may be spelt in different ways. For example:

> *cite*, *site*, and *sight*

Homonyms are words which are spelt in the same way but pronounced and meant in different ways. For example,

> *minute* [noun] and *minute* [adjective]

These words are pronounced in different ways when used to mean 'a unit of time' and 'tiny'.

Comment: This is a good start on an answer to the poster's question. To make it even more  useful, consider adding explanations of the terms _homonym_ and _heteronym_. If you have access to "professional definitions" of the terms (which the poster asks for), consider citing them, too.