# Can you wind the wind? Can you tear a tear? Can you lead to lead? What are these examples called?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, slang

These words are spelled the same. These words sound different. These words have different meanings.
This question can be answered and is about learning English. We really speak American in the United States. As a retired College teacher, my job is to ask questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homophones/Homonyms/Homographs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242510/homophones-homonyms-homographs)

Comment: If you have a question about learning English, you may like to look at [ell.se]

Comment: Periodic acid is an oxy-acid of the element iodine, number 53 in the Periodic Table.