# How can “Harold” and “Herald” ever sound the same?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, transatlantic-differences, received-pronunciation

I was reading a book¹ recently where the main protagonist is ﬁxated
on homonyms and has rules that proper nouns are not homonyms and
gives *Harold* and *herald* as an example of words that sound the
same but are not homonyms.

As an English speaker from the South of England this completely
threw me as I just can’t imagine how those two words could be
pronounced the same.  Can any US English speakers enlighten me on
how this can be?

For me they have two divergent vowel sounds and diﬀerent stress:
I pronounce *Harold* as “hah-ROlled” and *herald* as “heh-rALd”.

The book also said that *haul* and *hall* do ɴᴏᴛ sound the same,
which I find equally baﬀling. How can “haul” and “hall” ever be
pronounced differently?

---

#### Footnotes

1. The book is *Rain Reign* by Ann M Martin.  Its author seems to
   be from New York if that helps.

Comment: This might be about capitalization and spelling, not pronunciation. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/242517/425655). By the strict definition there, true homonyms must be spelled the same way, and even if there were a name "Herald," it might be distinguished as a capitonym.

Comment: In a British "cut-glass" accent 'Harold'  might be pronounced 'Herald'. For example a tourist tout once danced towards me exclaiming "Air hell-air!" (Oh, hello!) in a parody of such an accent.

Comment: (But to answer your underlying question, yes, especially where I am in the southern US, I could present many candidates who would loudly pronounce both as *HAYYYYYrald*. Makes the Christmas carol "Hark the..." a bit hayyyyr raising.)

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by "different stress"? Your transliteration capitalizes vowels in the second syllable, but I figured that was to emphasize difference rather than indicate stress. Do you pronounce either of them with the stress on the second syllable? I can't seem to find that pattern in any dictionary...

Comment: '[W]ords that sound the same but are not homonyms' has me baffled.

Comment: homonyms or homophones? AmE distinguishes herald and Harold. Not the same phonemes. [Cutting off the naysayers at the pass; Yes, one can always come up with exceptions to this but it is stiff a fact that the phonemes are different.] What do you mean by rhyme??

Comment: @Lambie what is the distinction? I pronounce them exactly the same.

Comment: @Casey It turns out some sites claim it's the same sound in AmE, and that can be but still, I would not call a friend called Harold, herald. So: Harald: ˈhærəld (noted as BrE). Now, when talking fast, the distinction may not be heard/made.

Comment: @Lambie By the extent to which it is “obvious” to both sides that it is or isn’t a homophone I would guess this is a regional distinction.

Comment: The question would be improved by showing your results from looking in some dictionaries.

Comment: As a British English speaker from the Midlands, I pronounce the second syllable the same in both words but not the first.

Comment: I do not understand why this question is off-topic.

Comment: A somewhat relevant factoid: When I pronounce "herald," my lips do not contort, but when I say "Harold," the right side of my mouth contorts a bit and my right cheek tightens a bit. I'm from Rochester, New York, where the words "bob" and "Bob" are respectively pronounced "baahb" (the sound a sheep makes, plus b) and "Baaaaaaahb" (the sound a sheep makes, only extended a bit, plus b). Some childhood friends of mine from the Philadelphia/New Jersey area pronounced the word "car" one way (kind of like "core"), whereas I, from Rochester, pronounced it differently (kind of like "caaaar-r").

Comment: @rhetorician Because you did not use IPA, nobody can understand what you meant by those pronunciations. Please revise.

Answer (score 5):

**First**, notice how most American speakers also rhyme *Harold* and *herald*
with *Gerald*, *caroled*, *imperiled*, and *double-barreled*.  This happens
because for most speakers of American English, stressed vowels before R
lose the tense–lax distinction that exists in words with those vowels that
don't have an R following them.

So even though the vowel phonemes in *heck* and *hat* and *hate* all
clearly differ from one another, as soon as you go replacing the final
consonant with R in each word, those vowels suddenly stop contrasting. Just which final vowel those all collapse into varies by speaker and
listener.  Some have only a tense vowel there, which yields [ˈheɹəld];
others have only a lax vowel instead, which yields [ˈhɛɹəld].

The same forces are at work in *hero* as to whether the vowel before the R
is the tense one of *peek* or the lax one of *pick*. Under tense–lax
neutralization, it simply doesn't matter because those two phonemes are no
longer distinguished in that position.

See the Wikipedia article on [English-language vowel changes before
historic
/r/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/)
for far more than everything you ever wanted to know about this truly voluminously lengthy area of study.

**Second**, the vowel in those two words’ second syllables is fully neutralized
into a schwa because it isn’t in a stressed syllable. It doesn’t matter
whether if stressed it would have been the vowel from *called* or the vowel
from *old*; it’s always just schwa when unstressed.

**Finally**, I can’t tell you why your writer claimed *haul* and *hall* are
pronounced differently, since as far as a I know, both are [hɔl]. The one
that’s different from *haul* is *howl*, since the latter rhymes with *owl*.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple. I would pronounce both words ˈhɛɹəld.

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Harold) confirms this and even lists the two words as homophones. It [has audio](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:en-us-herald.ogg) so you can hear what it sounds like too.

Comment: New Englander here, and I pronounce them differently. Where are you from?

Comment: @user888379 I grew up in Connecticut so I guess you’ll have to be more specific about “New England.”

Comment: Hi neighbor - southeast Massachusetts.

Comment: @user888379 I lived in the South Shore for 8 years and only just recently moved away. Honestly it never even occurred to me that someone might pronounce them differently. What is the difference?

Comment: I grew up on Lake Ontario, have been in CT, NYC, NJ and Philadelphia envrions for very many years. Phila area has at least 3 distinct regional accents. While each region pronounces these 2 words differently, they are still pronounced the same within the region(s)

Comment: +1 They are the same to me.  I grew up in Colorado.  The New Oxford American Dictionary shows both as | ˈhɛrəld |

Comment: According to the 2003 Harvard Dialect Study, [57% of Americans display the mary-mery-marry merger](https://www.businessinsider.com/merry-marry-mary-pronunciation-dialect-2018-12), which is what causes the first vowel in Harold and herald to sound the same.  Personally, having grown up in the Pacific Northwest, I was well into my 20s before I realized it was even possible to pronounce these words differently.

Comment: @Juhasz A-ha! It all comes together.

Comment: Only 57%? It's all one ever hears on radio or TV.